# HTML Video: Add an ID Tag when Person Clicks Play

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How do I add an id tag, when a person clicks presses the Play Button on HTML video? We are trying to track usage.

```
<video width="728" height="410" controls>
   <source src={testURL} type="video/mp4" />
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  video.setAttribute('id', 'video-playing');
  // send tracking data here
});
```

You can add an event listener to the play button of the HTML video and then use the setAttribute method to add an id tag to the video element. If this help!

Comment: can I do it with pure css?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener on your video tag and run your code whenever the video starts playing.

```
var video = document.querySelector("video"); // select video element

video.addEventListener("play", (event) => {
   // your tracking code goes here
});
```

Comment: can I do it with pure CSS?

Comment: Yes but most of browsers don't support it.
see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:playing
I think if you want to give style to playing video element javascript is your only option at the moment